# MediaWiki: increase session timeout

Tags: php, mediawiki, timeout, php.ini

I have a small MediaWiki wiki in a hosted website. It works pretty well, except that I can't find where to configure the session timeout.

Right now, my session expires while I'm editing pages. I've seen all kinds of recomendations, including touching the PHP settings, but I can't find any authoritative answer.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are referring to PHP session timeout, it is set in php.ini and depends further on your PHP version.

This could be through [session.gc_maxlifetime](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime) or [session.cache-expire](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cache-expire) or even [session.cookie_lifetime](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime).

See also this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes) for more info and this [article](http://frozenpc.net/2008/06/15/the-quest-to-conquer-the-php-session-timeout/).

Answer (score 0):

The session timeout configuration is php stuff, not mediawiki's.

Look for [session.cookie-lifetime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime) in your php.ini file.